Prevent grouping windows in nested app icon that are only accessible via right click?
in mac if I use the yellow "-" button on the left corner of a chrome window it puts it in the doc, but it groups it with the rest of the chrome app, then when I click the icon it doesn't bring all the windows up, i have to right click the icon to get that window back, is there a way to prevent this so each window is its own doc item? and not group?
